# Scroll div depending on parent position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a parent div with two child divs. The first child should be fixed when the parent is in viewport. The second child should scroll into position and overlap the first. Both child divs should be removed and follow the parent as soon as they reach the bottom of the parent.

Right now, I'm adding a class on scroll position but I'm not sure how to detect when the child is at bottom of parent and then remove the class.

```
var sticky = $('.sticky'),
  scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scroll >= 70) {
    sticky.addClass('fixed');
} else {
    sticky.removeClass('fixed');
}
```

How can I make the child divs follow the parent in the best way? I've tried to search for something similar what I want but couldn't find any good explanation.

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdornell/8fapygrf/1/) is what I've got so far.

Comment: Try this: https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2

Comment: If you want to use JS, [`stickyfloat` script](https://github.com/yairEO/stickyfloat) does what you want

Comment: Thank you for the answers, however I'm trying to solve it without a plugin as I think it would be easier to customize. But I'll have a look at the examples.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding this correctly, what you could do is measure `bottom` of parent `div` and child sticky `div` relative to the `document.body`, and if child element's bottom crossing parent's bottom you can remove `.fixed` class.

Something like this.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $('.sticky'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 70) {
  sticky.addClass('fixed')
  }else {
  sticky.removeClass('fixed');
  }
  if(getBottom('.sticky') >= getBottom('.holder')){
   sticky.removeClass('fixed');
  }
});

function getBottom(element){
  var $elm = $(element);
  var offset = $elm.offset();
  var top = offset.top;
  return top + $elm.outerHeight();

}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }

section { 
  height: 2000px;
  padding-top: 100px; 
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.holder {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.sticky { 
  top:30px; 
  left:10px;
  background: orange; 
  z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;
}

.other-div {
  background: gold;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Divs</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="other-div fixed">This div should stay fixed for a while</div>
    <div class="sticky">This div will become fixed on scroll</div>
  </div>
</section> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Jsfiddle of the above snippet https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/3ubshm4t/7/
Note, I made some css changes, which you can adjust as you need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry for the late reply. I've edit the code and add the sticky class to the other div as well but I have som issues with the movement of the divs. Right now, the first div behave correctly (your solution) but the other div jumps in position and then jumps outside of the parent when reaching the bottom. How can I make them both scroll smoothly in position? Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jdornell/f3o9goau/

Comment: Are you referring to the orange div? initially this is on `position: relative` and once scrolled past `70px` or more, it becomes `position: fixed`, and once container's bottom gets on par with this div, it becomes `position: relative` again. Isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, It's kind of what I want but I want the divs to get fixed position without jumping. As right now the orange div jumps into position. Why is that?

Comment: Because for relative positioning it remains relative to the container, but when position changed to fixed, then it is positioned relative to the screen's viewport and doesn't move when scrolled. When it's on fixed position, where you want to keep the div? CSS could be adjusted to make it smoother.

Comment: I see. I want the orange div to be maybe 20px down from the first div (as they are now) but I want the div to scroll to position instead of just get a fixed position. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: You could do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/ohfx5mp9/5/, note  I added a debounce function, and code is a bit spaghetti. Not sure why you want to turn the orange div into position fixed, you could scrolling effect by just updating `top` value.